# How many Public IP address can I attach to AWS Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, public, squid

I am trying to create a proxy server, with AWS instance. But When i tried attaching new ip address, its saying that there is a limit. How am i able to attach around 250 Ip per instance? or is it Possible to do so?

I have tried attaching it on AWS.

Comment: Are you wanting private IP addresses, or public IP addresses? What is your use-case? Normally when people asking such questions about IP addresses, they are attempting to violate website Terms of Service by scraping web content. We do not support such use-cases.

Comment: I am actually looking to add Public IP addresses. I am actually trying to create a proxy server for a client. The client is looking to use it for their internal Network or something.

Comment: It is possible, but it depends on how you intend to use them. Could you please edit your question to explain more about your use-case, so we can provide the most appropriate answer? For example, how will you be directing traffic in and out, in a way that isn't possible with one public IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bigger instances, you can have more private IP addresses and more interfaces.
And you can have one Elastic IP address (IPv4) per private IPv4 address.

Here is the complete info about the limitations, IP Addresses Per Network Interface Per Instance Type section.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html

So you can have multiple private IPs and (public) Elastic IPs.